# Why std::swap does not work with std::bitset<n> content?

Tags: c++, c++11, swap, bitset

Consider this unit test:

```
std::bitset<8> temp( "11010100" );
reverseBitSet( temp );
CPPUNIT_ASSERT( temp == std::bitset<8>( "00101011" ) );
```

This implementation works:

```
template<size_t _Count> static inline void reverseBitSet( std::bitset<_Count>& bitset )
{
    bool val;
    for ( size_t pos = 0; pos < _Count/2; ++pos )
    {
        val = bitset[pos];
        bitset[pos] = bitset[_Count-pos-1];
        bitset[_Count-pos-1] = val;
    }
}
```

While this one does not:

```
template<size_t _Count> static inline void reverseBitSet( std::bitset<_Count>& bitset )
{
    for ( size_t pos = 0; pos < _Count/2; ++pos )
    {
        std::swap( bitset[pos], bitset[_Count-pos-1] );
    }
}
```

Result is "11011011" instead of "00101011"

Why is swap doing it wrong?

Comment: bitset's `operator[]` returns a proxy object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
std::swap( bitset[pos], bitset[_Count-pos-1] );
```

should actual fail to compile. [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at) for a `std::bitset` doesn't return a reference, it returns a proxy object. That proxy object isn't an lvalue, so it cannot bind to the `T&` in `std::swap`. I'm assuming the fact that it compiles at all means that you're using MSVC which has an extension that allows binding temporaries to non-`const` references - at which point you're probably just swapping the proxies and not what the proxies are actually referring to.

---

Side-note: The name `_Count` is reserved by the standard, as is any other name which begins with an `_` followed by a capital letter.

Comment: But why is the doc you linked saying there's a version returning a reference (`(2) reference operator[]( std::size_t pos );`) ?

Comment: @jpo38 It doesn't say it returns a reference. It says it returns an object of type [`std::bitset::reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/reference) (which is, admittedly, confusing).

Comment: @jpo38 That _reference_ is a `std::bitset::reference`, that is the proxy object mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Got it, was confused by the name. You are right, I'm using MSVC for development.

Comment: Mentioning the flag needed to turn off this bug-inducing feature might be a good idea.  (`/Za`)

Comment: Actually, no, `vector<bool>` is even weirder - it has a *static member function* `swap` that works on `reference`. Who came up with this mess?

Comment: @T.C. Wait, how does std::swap work then if it's a static function?

Comment: It doesn't. I misread it as a friend non-member when I wrote the first comment. (libc++ has an extension that handles this correctly, though.)

Comment: @T.C. It does on the compilers I've tried somehow. Both compiles *and* swaps.

Comment: Hmm, libstdc++ is also nice enough to provide a pile of three `swap` overloads.

Comment: @T.C. I'll write up a proposal.

Comment: @Barry I think someone is working on a full bit_reference/_pointer/whatever suite. Might want to check with them.

Comment: @T.C. Ahh, [P0237](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0237r0.pdf)? Doesn't seem to have really been discussed in Oulu.